# GStreamer is hanging unexpectedly during dynamic change of elements

Tags: rust, gstreamer

We are using GStreamer to read the video stream off of network cameras and we observed a weird behaviour: our program would hang unexpectedly, without any kind of notice.

We, then, narrowed it down to the fact that our client had a very, *very* bad internet connection and we were able to reproduce the problem with just GStreamer and a tool to simulate bad networks.

I am attaching below both our tool to simulate bad networks and the example we've written to reproduce this behaviour.

Our tool to simulate bad networks uses `tc` to introduce a delay, packet loss and packet corruption.

Our example boils down to using a (subclassed) bin that can intercept EoS messages posted inside it, and a pipeline that reads a RTSP feed. The bin is then dinamically added and removed from the pipeline.

Are we doing something wrong? Could this be a bug in GStreamer itself?

---

`crapnet.sh`

```sh
sudo tc qdisc add dev wlp2s0 root netem \
    delay 500ms 480ms distribution normal \
    loss 30% 25% \
    corrupt 2%
```

---

`src/custom_bin.rs`

```rust
mod implementation {
    use {glib::subclass::prelude::*, gstreamer::subclass::prelude::*};

    use {
        glib::{glib_object_impl, glib_object_subclass, subclass::simple::ClassStruct},
        gstreamer::{subclass::ElementInstanceStruct, Bin, Message, MessageView},
        std::sync::{mpsc, Mutex},
    };

    pub struct CustomBin {
        pub(super) eos_guard: Mutex<Option<mpsc::SyncSender<()>>>,
    }

    impl ObjectImpl for CustomBin {
        glib_object_impl!();
    }

    impl ElementImpl for CustomBin {}

    impl BinImpl for CustomBin {
        fn handle_message(&self, bin: &Bin, message: Message) {
            let mut eos_guard = self.eos_guard.lock().unwrap();

            if let MessageView::Eos(_) = message.view() {
                if let Some(eos_guard) = eos_guard.take() {
                    return eos_guard.send(()).unwrap_or(());
                }
            }

            self.parent_handle_message(bin, message)
        }
    }

    impl ObjectSubclass for CustomBin {
        const NAME: &'static str = "GstCustomBin";
        type ParentType = Bin;
        type Instance = ElementInstanceStruct<Self>;
        type Class = ClassStruct<Self>;

        glib_object_subclass!();

        fn new() -> Self {
            Self {
                eos_guard: Mutex::new(None),
            }
        }
    }
}

use {
    glib::{prelude::*, subclass::prelude::*, translate::*},
    gstreamer::prelude::*,
};

use {
    glib::{glib_bool_error, glib_wrapper, subclass::simple::ClassStruct, BoolError, Object},
    gstreamer::{
        event, subclass::ElementInstanceStruct, Element, GhostPad, PadDirection, State, StateChangeError,
        StateChangeSuccess,
    },
    std::{sync::mpsc, time::Duration},
};

glib_wrapper! {
    /// A subclass of `gstreamer::Bin` that has customized behaviour for intercepting end-of-stream messages. This is necessary so that we can remove a branch from a `tee` and not bring down the entire pipeline.
    pub struct CustomBin(
        Object<
            ElementInstanceStruct<implementation::CustomBin>,
            ClassStruct<implementation::CustomBin>,
            CustomBinClass
        >
    ) @extends gstreamer::Bin, gstreamer::Element, gstreamer::Object;

    match fn {
        get_type => || implementation::CustomBin::get_type().to_glib(),
    }
}

unsafe impl Send for CustomBin {}
unsafe impl Sync for CustomBin {}

impl CustomBin {
    /// Instantiates the structure.
    pub fn new(name: Option<&str>) -> Self {
        Object::new(Self::static_type(), &[("name", &name)])
            .expect("Failed to instantiate `CustomBin` as an `Object`")
            .downcast()
            .expect("Failed to downcast `Object` to `CustomBin`")
    }

    /// Adds a ghost sink pad for the target element. It is assumed that the element belongs to the bin.
    pub fn add_ghost_sink_pad(&self, element: &Element) -> Result<(), BoolError> {
        let target_pad = element
            .get_static_pad("sink")
            .ok_or_else(|| glib_bool_error!("Failed to get sink pad from [{}]", element.get_name()))?;

        let ghost_pad = GhostPad::new(Some("sink"), PadDirection::Sink);
        ghost_pad.set_target(Some(&target_pad))?;

        self.add_pad(&ghost_pad)?;

        Ok(())
    }

    /// Installs an end-of-stream message guard, which will drop the end-of-stream message and then signal it was dropped.
    pub fn install_eos_guard(&self) -> mpsc::Receiver<()> {
        let super_self = implementation::CustomBin::from_instance(self);
        let mut eos_guard = super_self.eos_guard.lock().unwrap();

        let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::sync_channel(1);
        eos_guard.replace(sender);

        receiver
    }

    /// Sends an end-of-stream event to this bin. It will become an end-of-stream message once it reaches the sink.
    pub fn send_eos_event(&self) {
        let super_self = implementation::CustomBin::from_instance(self);
        let mut eos_guard = super_self.eos_guard.lock().unwrap();

        if !self.send_event(event::Eos::new()) {
            if let Some(eos_guard) = eos_guard.take() {
                eos_guard.send(()).unwrap_or(());
            }
        }
    }

    /// Flushes the data in the bin by sending an EoS event and then intercepting the resulting EoS message.
    pub fn flush(&self) -> Result<(), BoolError> {
        let eos_guard = self.install_eos_guard();
        self.send_eos_event();

        eos_guard
            .recv_timeout(Duration::from_secs(5))
            .map_err(|error| glib_bool_error!("Timed out waiting for the EoS guard during flush (error [{:?}])", error))
    }

    pub fn set_null_state(&self) -> Result<StateChangeSuccess, StateChangeError> {
        self.set_state(State::Null)
    }
}
```

---

`src/main.rs`

```rust
mod custom_bin;
use custom_bin::CustomBin;

use gstreamer::prelude::*;

use {
    glib::glib_bool_error,
    gstreamer::{ElementFactory, PadProbeReturn, PadProbeType, Pipeline, State},
    std::{error::Error, sync::mpsc, thread, time::Duration},
};

fn rtsp_location() -> String {
    String::from("rtspt://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov")
}

fn video_location(index: usize) -> String {
    format!("/home/valmirpretto/videos/video_{}.mp4", index)
}

fn instantiate_mp4_writer(location: &str) -> Result<CustomBin, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let queue = ElementFactory::make("queue", None)?;
    let h264parse = ElementFactory::make("h264parse", None)?;
    let mp4mux = ElementFactory::make("mp4mux", None)?;
    let filesink = ElementFactory::make("filesink", None)?;

    filesink.set_property("location", &location)?;

    let bin = CustomBin::new(None);
    bin.add(&queue)?;
    bin.add(&h264parse)?;
    bin.add(&mp4mux)?;
    bin.add(&filesink)?;

    queue.link(&h264parse)?;
    h264parse.link(&mp4mux)?;
    mp4mux.link(&filesink)?;

    bin.add_ghost_sink_pad(&queue)?;

    Ok(bin)
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    gstreamer::init()?;

    let rtspsrc = ElementFactory::make("rtspsrc", None)?;
    let rtph264depay = ElementFactory::make("rtph264depay", None)?;
    let tee = ElementFactory::make("tee", None)?;

    rtspsrc.set_property("location", &rtsp_location())?;
    tee.set_property("allow-not-linked", &true)?;

    let pipeline = Pipeline::new(None);
    pipeline.add(&rtspsrc)?;
    pipeline.add(&rtph264depay)?;
    pipeline.add(&tee)?;

    rtspsrc.connect_pad_added({
        let rtph264depay = rtph264depay.downgrade();

        move |_, src_pad| {
            if let Some(rtph264depay) = rtph264depay.upgrade() {
                let sink_pad = rtph264depay
                    .get_static_pad("sink")
                    .expect("Element rtph264depay without sink pad");

                if src_pad.can_link(&sink_pad) {
                    src_pad
                        .link(&sink_pad)
                        .expect("Failed to link after we checked it could");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    rtph264depay.link(&tee)?;

    pipeline.set_state(State::Playing)?;

    (0..).try_for_each::<_, Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>>(|index| {
        println!("Iteration [{}]", index);

        // Add bin to the pipeline
        let bin = instantiate_mp4_writer(&video_location(index))?;
        pipeline.add(&bin)?;
        bin.sync_state_with_parent()?;
        tee.link(&bin)?;

        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));

        // Remove bin from the pipeline
        let bin_sink_pad = bin
            .get_static_pad("sink")
            .ok_or_else(|| glib_bool_error!("Bin [{}] did not have a sink pad", bin.get_name()))?;

        let tee_src_pad = bin_sink_pad
            .get_peer()
            .ok_or_else(|| glib_bool_error!("Bin [{}] sink pad did not have a peer", bin.get_name()))?;

        let (signal_sender, signal_receiver) = mpsc::sync_channel(1);

        tee_src_pad.add_probe(PadProbeType::IDLE, {
            let bin = bin.downgrade();
            let pipeline = pipeline.downgrade();
            let tee = tee.downgrade();

            move |tee_src_pad, _| {
                if let Some(bin) = bin.upgrade() {
                    if let Some(pipeline) = pipeline.upgrade() {
                        bin.flush().expect(&format!("Could not flush bin [{}]", bin.get_name()));

                        pipeline
                            .remove(&bin)
                            .expect(&format!("Could not remove bin [{}] from pipeline", bin.get_name()));

                        bin.set_null_state()
                            .expect(&format!("Could not set null state of bin [{}]", bin.get_name()));

                        signal_sender
                            .send(())
                            .expect(&format!("Could not signal that bin [{}] is done", bin.get_name()));
                    }
                }

                if let Some(tee) = tee.upgrade() {
                    tee.release_request_pad(tee_src_pad);
                }

                PadProbeReturn::Remove
            }
        });

        signal_receiver
            .recv_timeout(Duration::from_secs(5))
            .map_err(|error| glib_bool_error!("Timed out waiting for EoS (error [{:?}])", error))?;

        Ok(())
    })?;

    Ok(())
}
```